# On which sites can you earn the You Got Splunk! hat?

Tags: support, tags, stack-exchange, winter-bash-2022

The trigger for the [You Got Splunk!](https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/you-got-splunk) hat is as follows:

> Ask or answer a question with a tag that includes the string "data". Your post must have score 1 or above.

Is it possible to earn this hat on every site in the network? Or is it just limited to a handful of sites?

Comment: Amusing statistic: There's a [Data](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-data) tag on our SciFi site, and a [Moderator](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3804/ancientswordrage?tab=topactivity#winter-bash) has the hat.

Comment: I earned this on Worldbuilding, purely coincidental :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) can help here; it's possible to compare queries across different sites, and [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1688653/number-of-tags-on-a-site-satisfying-a-certain-pattern?TagName=data) lists how many tags contain 'data' in their name. (How many *questions* have the tag is more difficult, since a question may have multiple 'data'-like tags.)

[image]

There are just over 60 sites in the network which don't qualify (so about 120 which do); of course, asking a question and creating a tag just to earn a hat will be frowned upon.

If you're curious whether any of your old posts would qualify for the hat, you can check [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1692600/i-would-have-got-splunk) - it needs your network account ID, which you can find in the URL of [your network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current).

Please note that SEDE is updated only once a week, on Sunday morning, so the results might be a bit stale.